# ModelBuilder Iterator - how to change values and names respectively

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, iterator

I have a table (value.csv) with two fields (Expression, Name) that I would like to iterate through within a model.

I want the model to iterate through a series of SQL expressions (e.g. Value > 1, Value > 2, etc.). I think this part is working.

How do I get the iterator to rename each new shapefile according to the Name field in my table (i.e. Name1, Name2, etc.)

EDIT: I've added a screenshot for the set null parameters (which I am currently doing manually).

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: Added the Iterate Row Selection and Get Field Value to my model and after some tinkering it eventually worked. Here is the full model:

[image]

Comment: What parameter values do you have configured on your Set Null tool?  A screenshot may be the best way to show that.  What happens when you run your model?

Comment: Thx. I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you will need to use is **Iterate Row Selection** instead. See the [ArcGIS help page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_6DAC76648FEB466388AD883E141D3960) for more information.

If you then use **[Get Field Value](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-model-only-tools-in-modelbuilder.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C6447050F5D34A8DA2121D405EC52F69)** you will be able to use the Name/Expression in other tools.

Comment: thx, got it to work with your input. It also seems that I first need to convert my .csv to a dbf.